# How to control when a jQuery slideToggle(); which is position:absolute; is higher than viewport?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a slideToggle(); menu which is positioned absolutely on the bottom of the page. The slideToggle(); is going to show big content and sometimes this ends up being taller than the viewport.

My question is, how do I prevent the menu to:

1 - Not going on the top of the logo as they are both on the sidebar of my website

2 - When it reaches a height taller than the viewport, this will be scrollable

To explain myself better, I'd like the content of my menu, once is shown by slideToggle(); and whenever is taller than the viewport's height minus logo's height, to stop right below my logo and to continue expanding downwards if that's the case, and that I am able to scroll it down despite its position:absolute.

Does anyone have an idea on how I can achieve that? Please have a look at the snippet.

```js
$( "#click" ).click(function() {
  $( ".content" ).slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.logo {
  background: #11a1d6;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
}

.list {
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
}

.content {
  background: #082965;
  height: 10000px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="logo"></div>

<ul class="list">
 <li id="click">
   Click me
   <div class="content"></div>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your list is `bottom: 20px `, that's what it'll do. You'll have to adjust your strategy

Comment: Exactly, it is the only way for me to position the list on the bottom of the sidebar, but that will stop being scrollable and it will result being on the top of my logo. What strategy should I use instead?

Comment: What's your use-case? What are you trying to achieve product wise?

Comment: I have a portfolio website, sidebar on the left and content on the right. Sidebar contains: logo and menu. This menu has two cores functionalities: 1. Provide a list of links for my artworks 2. Load content (like about summary and contact details) on my sidebar with a click. Technically I could solve everything by simply not positioning the menu on the bottom with position:absolute; but I just don't like the layout in this way. On my sidebar I like logo on the top and menu on the bottom: https://imgur.com/a/qFLqDF4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need an additional wrapper for your `.content` that has `overflow-y: hidden` and `height` set to the max height available. To determine this height you need a function that runs after your DOM is loaded and adds this to your `.content-wrapper`:

```
function setContentMaxHeight() {
  let containerHeight = $('.container').height()
  let logoMargin = $('.logo').offset().top;
  let logoHeight = $('.logo').height();
  let listHeight = $('.list').height();
  let listMargin = 20;
  let maxHeight =  containerHeight - ( 2 * logoMargin ) - logoHeight - ( 2 * listMargin) - listHeight;
  $('.content-wrapper').css({
      'height': maxHeight + 'px'
  });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    setContentMaxHeight();
    window.onresize = setContentMaxHeight; // detect the window resize and rerun the function
});
```

[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d4crq5z3/5/)

Comment: This dope, final answer. Thank you for your time, I upvoted you but since my account it's fresh it won't be displayed.

Comment: glad i could help

Comment: Actually, as I previously wrote but then cancelled, what if I wanted the content to scroll within the container together with the logo, once it's opened?

Comment: The simplest way would be to move the `overflow-y: scroll;` up to the container element. And then toggle a class on the list element in the slide callback function that changes the lists position from absolute to inherit. (Otherwise your container will not grow with the content height. Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3o5jfghw/) You will need to add some width to the container too, since it now has to fit the scrollbar